pick a word from multiple words in a column using snow SQL
I have a column with this kind of data (web.at.menu.planning.clicked). I want to filter columns with  .clicked so I used a like operator where column like '%.clicked' then column. But it is showing me nulls. How do I further proceed with this ? Any thoughts ?
I did try using like and trim operators but nothing works

What data type is that column where the "data" that you want parsed is? Also, show us what you tried so far.

you can try using the like operator
with temp as
(SELECT 'web.at.menu.planning.clicked' as fld1 UNION 
SELECT 'web.at.menu.planning.Not_click' as fld1  UNION 
SELECT 'web.at.menu.planning.click' as fld1  )
select * from temp where fld1 like '%clicked%';

